# how to get tweets containing specific keyword from multiple users using twitter API

Tags: api, twitter

I am trying to search for the tweets from multiple users which contains the specific keyword.
Is there any specific twitter API to do so? and If there is, can you tell me how to get the search result?
I need to pass at least 10 users at a time and 1 keyword.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with Node.js, then there is a helpful npm package ['twit'](https://github.com/ttezel/twit).

For searching the tweets with the specific keyword:

```
    // I only want to see tweets about my favorite fruits. Same result as doing { track: 'bananas,oranges,strawberries' }
    
var stream = T.stream('statuses/filter', { track: ['bananas', 'oranges', 'strawberries'] })
```

Comment: I want  get tweets from multiple users which contains given keyword. is there any way?

Comment: @sweety You need to have developer access to do so. Apply [here](developer.twitter.com). There is no other way to get access to Twitter API. [Intoduction tutorial](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/search/introduction) on searching tweets contain certain keywords. Tutotial on building queries: [one](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/search/integrate/build-a-rule), [two](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/search/quick-start). Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

```html
var Twit = require('twit');
var util = require('util');

var config =require('./config');

var T = new Twit(config)
var stream = T.stream('statuses/filter', { follow: ['56488059','2227355222'] , track: ['Covid','Corona'] , language: ['en'] });




stream.on('tweet', (tweet) => {
    console.log(tweet)
    console.log('---------------------')
    }
 );
```

follow contains the user_ids , and track contains the keywords.

```html
module.exports = {
    
    consumer_key : "",
    consumer_secret : "",
    access_token : "",
    access_token_secret : ""
    
   }
```

config.js contains the credentials from twitter developer.